# Dancing at Bar Mitzvah Celebration during Sefira

Tags: minhag, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, dance

I attended a Bar Mitzvah last night, and there was so-called "sefira music" playing, and there was also dancing. As far as I recall learning, there are some justifications for listening to such music, but I don't know of any *heter* to dance during Sefira. There were some local Rabbis in attendance, and no-one said anything, leading me to believe there is a *heter* for it.

My question is, what is the *heter* to dance at a Bar Mitzvah celebration during Sefira?

Comment: Maybe they are makil since it's only a minhag that's not mentioned in the Talmud? (half-serious...)

Comment: I THINK I saw something mentioned in SA that allows Bar Mitzvah dancing. I could be wrong ... I'll hunt a bit, B"N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Seder Pesach K'hilchoso - Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Grossman](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95.html?id=VwONAQAACAAJ) says that if it is Bo Bayom of the Bar Mitzva boy or if there is a Siyum at the beginning of the celebration dancing is permitted.

I have heard that there are many other contemporary Halachic authorities that agree with this ruling. Most likely even if there are those that prohibit it, they would not protest it due to the authorities that permit it.